# Contact form php

Tags: php, forms, contacts

The HTML code is this

```
<form class="rnd5" action="mail.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-input clear">
          <label for="name">Nume <span class="required">*</span><br>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" size="22">
          </label>
          <label for="email">Email <span class="required">*</span><br>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" size="22">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-message">
          <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="25" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
        <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button small orange">
          &nbsp;
          <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button small grey">
        </p>
      </form>
```

And the php code is this one :

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "pascal.m.cornel@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

But it doesnt work.... i don't know what to do , i need some help here please.

Comment: What do you mean by _But it doesnt work_ ??? Have you get any error or where you stuck????

Comment: What's problem, mail not sent or any other problem you're facing?

Answer (score 1):

> If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some Unix mail transfer agents (most notably » qmail) replace LF by CRLF automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

In your case, neither \r\n nor \n is needed as you're only using a single extra header.

Comment: so i should just delete \r\n?

Comment: \r\n is used to seperate multiple extra headers. In your case, you can just remove it as you're only using a single extra header.